# Back to app when press on notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am making a notification and when user press notification it will back to app instead of starting new activity. becourse i have Countdown timer on background and i don't want start new activity. Here is my notification code:

```
//somecode
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 1, Mainactivity.class, 0);

                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                builder.setAutoCancel(false);
                builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
                builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");               
                builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setOngoing(true);
                builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
                builder.setNumber(100);
                builder.build();

                myNotication = builder.getNotification();
                manager.notify(11, myNotication)
```

the notification works fine but when i press notification it start new activity instead of my current app page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to your app's Manifest.

If there already is an `Activity` instance with the same type at the top of stack in the caller Task then this `launchmode` means that a new `Activity` is not created. Instead, the `Activity` on the stack will receive the `Intent`